# How to fix the title position of a plot after using color bar and slider

Tags: python, 3d, slider, title, colorbar

I have the following codes which use slider to choose which plots I want to show.

The input are three .xlsx files. The codes read the files and plot each of them by using slider to choose it.

Now I have the problem of fixing the position of the title of the plot.

The codes are shown below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import ipywidgets as wg
import pandas as pd
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
%matplotlib widget

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
rm = pd.read_excel("test_3d.xlsx", header = None)
rm1 = pd.read_excel("test_3d1.xlsx", header = None)
rm2 = pd.read_excel("test_3d2.xlsx", header = None)

rec = np.shape(rm)
rmm = np.concatenate([rm,rm1,rm2])
np.min(rmm)


X = np.arange(1,rec[1]+1,1)
Y = np.arange(1,rec[0]+1,1)
x , y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)


# Design a slider to choose which simulation to show 
slider = wg.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=2, description='this is slider')
slideroutput = wg.Output()
display(slider, slideroutput)


# Initial plots
ax.cla()
plt.title(f"Noise Result {str(slider.value)}")
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
ax.set_zlim(math.floor(np.min(rmm)), math.ceil(np.max(rmm)))
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.02f}')

# After your choice
numberonslider = []
def on_value_change(change):
    with slideroutput:
        numberonslider.append(change['new'])
        if numberonslider[-1] == 0:
            ax.cla()
            plt.title(f"Noise Result {str(slider.value)}")
            surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, rm, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
            ax.set_zlim(math.floor(np.min(rmm)), math.ceil(np.max(rmm)))
            ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
            ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.02f}')
        elif numberonslider[-1] == 1:
            ax.cla()
            plt.title(f"Noise Result {str(slider.value)}")
            surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
            ax.set_zlim(math.floor(np.min(rmm)), math.ceil(np.max(rmm)))
            ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
            ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.02f}')
        elif numberonslider[-1] == 2:
            ax.cla()
            plt.title(f"Noise Result {str(slider.value)}")
            surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, rm2, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
            ax.set_zlim(math.floor(np.min(rmm)), math.ceil(np.max(rmm)))
            ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
            ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.02f}')
    
    
# Customize the z axis.
slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')


# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.87, 0.25, 0.01, 0.5]) 
cb = fig.colorbar(surf, cax = cbaxes)  
cb.set_label('dBm', rotation=270)


plt.show()
```

My question is when I run the code (before move the slider), it shows

[image]

Now, after moving the slider, the title (Noise Result) of the plot moves to the top of the color bar.

[image]

How to fix this problem?    Thanks!